# Validar que un numero es decimal o entero

Tags: c#

Quiero hacer un programa en el que el usurario ingrese una cantidad, y después le diga que si la cantidad es un numero entero o decimal. y para verificarlo quiero que lo haga en un "if". Intente hacerlo pasando la cantidad a int, pero a la hora de la resta siempre sale 0, y supuesta mente tendría que tomar solo la parte entera ya que es un int.

```
double a;

Console.WriteLine("ingrese una cantidad");
a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

int y = Convert.ToInt32(a);

double b = a - y;

if (b == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("es un numero entero");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("es un decimal");
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: La resta siempre te da 0 porque `Convert.ToInt32(a)`, o lo que es lo mismo `(int)a`, elimina la parte decimal automáticamente (lo cual es lógico: un `int` por definición no tiene parte decimal).

Comment: ¿Has intentado sacar el residuo de `a%1`. Si es un número entero el resultado del residuo debe ser cero. En cualquier otro caso daría otro número.

Answer (score 1):

!Buenas!

Realmente lo que quieres hacer no es saber que tipo de dato estas manejando, sino, **adivinar** el tipo de dato que el usuario va a introducir. Digo esto por que no sabes el tipo de dato que introducirá el usuario, por lo tanto no puedes declarar una variable sin saber el dato que le corresponde...

Para saber un tipo de dato, y que devuelva un `true` o `false`, tienes el método `GetType()` pero en tu caso no se puede aplicar.

Por lo tanto tienes que hacerlo de forma "manual". Y seria de la siguiente forma:

```
        string numero;
        bool entero = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Introduce un numero: ");
        numero = Console.ReadLine();

        char[] test = numero.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
        {
            if (test[i] == '.')
            {
                entero = false;
            }
        }

        try
        {
            if (entero)
            {
                Convert.ToInt32(numero);
                Console.WriteLine("Es un numero entero.");
            }
            else
            {
                Convert.ToDouble(numero);
                Console.WriteLine("Es un numero decimal.");
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Has introducido una letra.");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Con esto, da igual lo que el usuario introduzca. Te explico un poco:

> Para que un numero sea decimal a de tener un `.` y sino, pues es un
>   numero entero o simplemente te arroja una exception. Por ello en el
>   bucle `for` comparo que lo que ha introducido el usuario no lleve ese
>   `.` Y como no se lo que va a introducir, guardo el valor en una
>   variable `string` para "jugar" con el código ASCII.
>
> Si encuentra un `.` pues la variable `entero` pasa a ser `false` y ya
>   solo queda verificar esta variable, si es `true` convertimos la cadena
>   en `int` y si es `false` pues la pasamos a `double` y con el `try
>   catch` controlamos que el usuario introduzca una letra.

Por otro lado, esta parte: `char[] test = numero.ToCharArray();` es simplemente para pasar el tipo `string` a un array tipo `char` para verificar carácter a carácter que no lleva un `.`

Answer (score 1):

Una solución más simple es sacar el residuo de dividir `numeroParaVerificar/1`. Para sacar el residuo se utiliza el operador `%`.

Por lo tanto, si el residuo es un número distinto a cero, significa que tu número no es un entero.

Hice este pequeño código que ejemplifica como puedes obtener el resultado:

```
using System;

class MainClass {
    public static void Main (string[] args) {
        double[] numbers = { 
            1.034923, 
            2.0,
            3.141615478, 
            4,
            5.000000000001,
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            double number = numbers[i];
            double remainder = number % 1;

            if (remainder != 0) 
                Console.WriteLine(number + " no es entero.");
            else
                Console.WriteLine(number + " es entero.");
        }
    }
}
```

Puedes probarlo tu mismo en el siguiente repl.it:
https://replit.com/@JacoboTapia/VerifyInteger-1#main.cs

Comment: Gracias, no conocía esta forma

Answer (score 0):

te escribo un código para saber si el dato introducido por el usuario es un entero o no

```
Console.WriteLine("ingrese una cantidad.");
if(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out cantidad))
{
    Console.WriteLine("No es entero.");
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("Es entero.");
}
```

Como puedes ver, el algoritmo verifica si el dato es convertible a entero empleando el método [Int32.TryParse](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Esto es ciertamente útil y el OP debería añadirlo a su código, pero la pregunta es cómo distinguir si el número introducido por el usuario en un número entero o un número con parte decimal.

Comment: Hola @Konamiman, leyendo la pregunta simplemente se especifica "que el usurario ingrese una cantidad, y después le diga que si la cantidad es un numero entero o decimal". Si aplicas el `TryParse` de un entero y le pasas un número con parte decimal, devolverá false. Un número decimal siempre tiene parte entera por lo que validar si existe parte decimal a mi modo de ver no es correcto.

Comment: `int.TryParse` sí hará lo que dices, pero lo que debería usarse en este caso es `decimal.TryParse`, se me había pasado ese detalle al leer tu código. Por otro lado, usar `decimal.TryParse` más luego `decimal.Truncate` permite validar ambas cosas: que la entrada es un número, y si es entero o decimal.

Answer (score 0):

[Decimal.Truncate](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.decimal.truncate?view=netframework-4.8) al rescate (más un poco de control de errores, que nunca viene mal):

```
string entrada = Console.ReadLine();
decimal numero;
if(!decimal.TryParse(entrada, out numero))
  //No es un número válido, lanzar una excepción o mostrar un error

decimal parteEntera = decimal.Truncate(numero);
var tieneParteDecimal = (parteEntera != numero);
```

No directamente relacionado pero conviene saber: el separador de parte decimal que `decimal.Parse` reconocerá depende de la cultura del sistema ([CultureInfo.CurrentCulture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netframework-4.8)). Si quieres asegurarte de que dicho separador es siempre el punto (`.`), usa esta sobrecarga del método: `decimal.TryParse(entrada, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out numero)`